# N number of random numbers between -1 and 1 python

Tags: python-3.x, random, numbers

How to generate N number of float random numbers between -1 and +1 in python. It appears that random.choice () or random.uniform() is not working. Is there any other option lets say to produce 1000 random numbers between [-1,1]

Comment: `random.random() * 2 - 1` then repeat N times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have tested and it works for this range

```
random.uniform(-1, 1)
```